# XAMPP - "This webpage is not available"

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I am trying my first Hello World app using php and xampp. I've been getting errors so far and been working through the problems one by one. So far I have:

1. Saved the php file ("hello.php") on C:\xampp\htdocs. The following line is in between html "body" tags.

   ```
   <?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?>
   ```
2. Disabled World Wide Web Services from using port 80 as that caused an error on my xampp control panel.
3. Disabled mySQL56 from using port 3306 as also caused an error on my xampp control panel. At this point, when I turn on xampp control panel, everything looks fine (I say this because all i can see is blue and black writing) except it says I am not running with admin rights.
4. When I type in http://localhost/hello.php on either Chrome or Firefox, I get "This webpage is not available." error.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Further notes: I am using Windows 7 and haven't downloaded anything from PHP.

I apologise for perhaps a too wide question. I have tried to be as specific as possible by outlining all actions I have taken.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about the error? Do you see a HTTP error code, e.g. 503 for Service Unavailable?

Comment: Sure, when I click on the "details" button on the error page, it says "Google Chrome's connection attempt to localhost was rejected. The website may be down, or your network may not be properly configured." Underneath that, there is a "Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" note

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running control panel with admin rights. Right click on control panel icon and select "Run as administrator". Also it would help if you pasted here the messages that you get in control panel when you start apache (mysql is not needed to run your hello.php file since you don't access any database).

Comment: Thanks - ran as admin and started Apache. Now working.

Answer (score 4):

**If admin privileges did not work for you, and you are SURE that your firewall *or some other app* is NOT blocking Apache** ... then:

## Make sure, you are visiting the same port, that your Apache is listening to...

Basic http://localhost/ is actually requesting port 80

Secure https://localhost/ is requesting port 443

So in Control Panel, check what ports are 'on' for Apache:

Usually the first one of 2 ports is the one you want - if there is 80, use http://localhost/ ,

if there is 443, you would use https://localhost/

...and lastly - if there is NONE of these 2, you need to write your URL like:

http://localhost:PORT_NUMBER

I hope this will help someone :)

Comment: Thanks! You saved my day. I had to change port number from config file just to make apache start, but glad to know that I need to add the new port number besides `localhost`.

Comment: Glad I could help, and Yea, that's common issue, e.g. if you are using Skype :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you have changed the port numbers of Apache when configuring XAMPP,

you have to run the localhost as,

http://localhost:PORT_NUMBER

ex: 89 is the port number.So it can be written as localhost:89

You can find the allocated port number from XAMPP control panel.[XAMPP Control Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQexg.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've actually also had quite some issues with XAMPP now, so I bet it's a problem with the software setup. Here are some reasons that could cause your roblem.

1. Try the local URL http://127.0.0.1/hello.php
2. Check the XAMPP control panel to see if Apache is running properly
3. Restart your computer
4. Run Apache with Administrator privileges
5. Check the Apache server configuration

Some less probable causes

5. Make sure no Firewall or other software is blocking the applications,
       specifically port 80 [e.g., Skype may do that; can be disabled in a
       menu]. You might want to try out Windows Firewall to try it out ( make
       sure to reenable it afterwards )
6. Check the `hosts` file in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`

Alternatively, try connecting to the standard XAMPP page located at the local website roots `localhost` / `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Hey thank you, now working as I ran it with admin privileges.