# Xampp: webpage is not available

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

I have installed xampp(32bit) on Windows8.1(64bit).I'm working on, Apache and MySql. The server Apache and MySql services are running properly on the Xampp control panel. But when I run the localhost on my web browser it just shows,

> This webpage is not available
>
> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

whenever I installed this xampp 1st time, it runs OK but after restarting it, this error comes up.
Even I configured
 1. Appache(httpd.conf)
 2. appache(httpd-ssl.conf)
But i'm still not able to open that localhost on web browser!

Comment: [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28508774/xampp-this-webpage-is-not-available)

Comment: First check if the http port is open at all. Easiest and most transparent is to use the telnet utility for that: `telnet localhost 80`. If you see the greeting string the http server sends, then your issue is the page logic, if you run into a timeout or are refused, then you have an issue with your http server. In that case you have to take a look at the http servers log files for more information.