# need to insert in table "doctors" (id is autoincrement).dont know what is wrong with query .I get error-"webpage not available ". help to resolve it

Tags: php, html, mysql

`<?php`

```
$host = 'localhost';
$username = 'uai';
$password = '';
$database = 'Pharma';
$table = 'doctors';
mysql_connect( $host, $username, $password )
or  die(" could not connect to database..." .mysql_error ());
mysql_select_db($database)
or die ("Could not connect to database..." .mysql_error ());
$firstname =$_POST['firstname'];
$lastname =$_POST['lastname'];
$speciality =$_POST['speciality'];
$hospital=$_POST['hospital'];
$city=$_POST['city'];
$state=$_POST['state'];
$country=$_POST['country'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO $table (firstname,lastname,speciality,hospital,city,state,country)VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname','$speciality','$hospital','$city','$state','$country')";
$result =mysql_query($sql);
if ($result) {
echo "New record created successfully";
}
else {
echo "Insertion Error: ";
}
?>
<?php
mysql_close();
?>
```

`<form action="doctors.php" method = "post">`

```
<table align="center">
<tr>
<td>First Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="firstname" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Last Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="lastname" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Speciality:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="speciality" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Hospital:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="hospital" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>City:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="city" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>State:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="state" /></td>
<tr>
<td>Country:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="country" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table align="center">
<tr>
<td><center> <input type="submit" name="submit" >
<input type="reset" name="clear">
</td>
</form>
```

Comment: missing `'` in `$country=$_POST[country'];`

Answer (score 0):

Missing `'` in `$country=$_POST[country'];`

Change this `$country=$_POST[country'];` to `$country=$_POST['country'];`

```
$country=$_POST['country'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO $table (firstname,lastname,speciality,hospital,city,state,country)VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname','$speciality','$hospital','$city','$state','$country')";
$result =mysql_query($sql);
if ($result) {
```

**Updated Code:**

Change this

```
mysql_connect( $host, $username, $password ) or  die(" could not connect to database..." .mysql_error ());
mysql_select_db($database) or die ("Could not connect to database..." .mysql_error ());
```

to

```
$con = mysql_connect( $host, $username, $password ) or  die(" could not connect to database..." .mysql_error ());
$db = mysql_select_db($database,$con) or die ("Could not connect to database..." .mysql_error ());
```

**Syntax**

> mysql_select_db(connection,dbname);

```
connection =>   Required. Specifies the MySQL connection to use
dbname =>       Required. Specifies the default database to be used
```

So, connection and dbname are required field. Pass connection value to mysql_select_db.

[**Note**: `mysql functions` are depreciated. Use `PDO` or `mysqli.* functions`]

```
<?php

$host = 'localhost';
$username = 'uai';
$password = '';
$database = 'Pharma';
$table = 'doctors';

$con = mysql_connect( $host, $username, $password ) or  die(" could not connect to database..." .mysql_error ());
$db = mysql_select_db($database,$con) or die ("Could not connect to database..." .mysql_error ());

$firstname =$_POST['firstname'];
$lastname =$_POST['lastname'];
$speciality =$_POST['speciality'];
$hospital=$_POST['hospital'];
$city=$_POST['city'];
$state=$_POST['state'];
$country=$_POST['country'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO $table (firstname,lastname,speciality,hospital,city,state,country)VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname','$speciality','$hospital','$city','$state','$country')";
$result =mysql_query($sql);
if ($result) {
echo "New record created successfully";
}
else {
echo "Insertion Error: ";
}
?>
<?php
mysql_close();
?>
```

---

**Using mysqli.* functions**

> MySQL extension officially deprecated since PHP 5.5.0 in late 2012 and
>   it will be removed in the future. The alternatives since PHP 5 and
>   later are MySQLi ("i" stands from "improved") and PDO (PHP Data
>   Objects).

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$username = 'uai';
$password = '';
$database = 'Pharma';
$table = 'doctors';

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password,$database) or die(" could not connect to database..." .mysqli_connect_error());

$firstname =$_POST['firstname'];
$lastname =$_POST['lastname'];
$speciality =$_POST['speciality'];
$hospital=$_POST['hospital'];
$city=$_POST['city'];
$state=$_POST['state'];
$country=$_POST['country'];

$result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO $table (firstname,lastname,speciality,hospital,city,state,country)VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname','$speciality','$hospital','$city','$state','$country')");

if ($result) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
}
else {
    echo "Insertion Error: ";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: What error you getting there ? Please edit your question with full error. @ganeshvasanth

Comment: what is the page name of this page. Double check in your `<form></form>` tag action attribute @ganeshvasanth

Comment: form action=doctors.php

Comment: and this is doctors.php page. So, kindly post your `<form></form>` also. Then, only we can find. One more thing. doctors.php is in same folder.?? @ganeshvasanth

Comment: I've changed few codes. Please have a look to it @ganeshvasanth

Comment: Try running control panel with admin rights. Right click on control panel icon and select "Run as administrator".  @ganeshvasanth Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28508774/xampp-this-webpage-is-not-available

Comment: but the other programs to insert data are working expect this.